# How to run a static method of a generic type?

Tags: python, python-typing

```
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def work():
        print("works")

T = TypeVar('T', bound=A)
class B(Generic[T]):
    @staticmethod
    def execute():
        T.work() # this doesn't work
        # A.work() # but this would work

B[A].execute()
```

`T.work()` doesn't work because T has no function work. Why doesn't it have? How can I change T to type from which I could run function work?

Comment: `T.work()` doesn't make sense. `T` is a type variable. What do you expect that to do?

Comment: So how can I convert TypeVar to type? I want to somehow change T to A to make it work.

Comment: check https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html

Comment: `B[A]` has no runtime effect. These are *type annotations*. Your `B` class needs to be provided the dependency somehow. Probably as an argument to the constructor. In that sense, it really shouldn't be a staticmethod (which likely just shouldn't be a static method to begin with anyway, why not just a function?)

Comment: @MateuszKisielMateuszKisiel there is nothing to convert. you are confusing type annotations with runtime, concrete types. Type annotations exist mainly for the use of people *reading* source code or third-party static analysis, e.g. `mypy`.

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga honestly I am not getting it. I am facing the following situation: I wanted to implement class that is a wrapper on `csv.DictWriter` templated by pydantic `BaseModel` subtype. I want to create a `csv.DictWriter` instance to be created on wrapper instance create and give it all field names from the pydantic subclass. I know that subclass of pydantic `BaseModel` has `__fields__` member, but for mypy it's not discover and it complains on that.

Comment: Hold on. The problem is that @Rozrewolwerowanyrewolwer wants to use this generic class without instantiating it. It does not make sense. But it WOULD make sense if he wanted to use it in an instance method. And I have a feeling that noone took that into account in this discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from typing import Type, TypeVar, Generic


class A:
    @staticmethod
    def work():
        print("works")


T = TypeVar("T", bound=A)


class B(Generic[T]):
    @staticmethod
    def execute(a_type: Type[T]):
        a_type.work()


class ChildOfA(A):
    @staticmethod
    def work():
        print("works even better")


B.execute(ChildOfA)
```

This code says that it `works even better`.